# Loading 64 bit generic ODBC type provider from Visual Studio

Tags: f#, odbc, 64-bit, visual-studio-2019, type-providers

I have latest Visual Studio 20019 and I'm building a .NET Framework 4.8 console app.

I've installed the SQL Provider nuget package and I'm trying to use a **64-bit** odbc driver, following the [ODBC doc](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/odbc.html).

I've set `x64` as platform in the F# project properties as shown below

[image]

But when I type the classical code

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql 
[<Literal>] 
let dnsConn = @"DSN=foo" 
type db = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.ODBC, dnsConn>
let ctx = db.GetDataContext()
```

there is an

```
Error IM014, message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

and a red squiggly line in the editor, like below.
[image]

### What I've tried to do

I've checked that the DSN is ok by implementing an equivalent access via traditional C# code

```
static void OdbcSelect(OdbcConnection conn)
{
    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn))
    {
```

and it's all fine.
I've also opened an [issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/686) on github, where they suggested to

> Try VS Code, I think that is running FSI/FSC on 64bit by default

Indeed I've tried `fsianycpu` from the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 and the following command does not throw any error

```
- type db = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.ODBC, dnsConn>;;
type db = SqlDataProvider<...>
```

But I really do need to use Visual Studio 2019...
And anyway if I must use Visual Sutdio Code because it is the only way to solve this problem (but is it really the only way?), I have to port the project from .Net Framework to Core (right?) and after a first try in .NET Code I get an

```
error FS3033:
Errore segnalato dal provider di tipi 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider': 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Odbc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

### Quick recap of the situation

I on Win10 64-bit and I am using VS2019 with .NET Framework and/or VS Code with .NET Core.
Notice that with pure odbc connection, command and data-reader (code below) both VS2019 and VS Code can build and run fine, without any issues with odbc at compile and runtime.

```
let conn = new OdbcConnection(dnsConn)
conn.Open()
let cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn)
let DR = cmd.ExecuteReader()
while (DR.Read()) do
```

So the build error comes out only when I introduce

```
type db = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.ODBC, dnsConn> `
```

Comment: Make sure the "Prefer 32-bit" option is unchecked.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044352/f-type-provider-that-uses-x64-libraries-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

As far as Visual Studio and .NET Framework are concerned, it all boils down to Visual Studio 2019 still being a 32-bit app.

So I've installed also the 32 bit version of my specific odbc driver and configured `myDSN32` (only for local development purposes).

Then I've been able to actually open the connection through the 64-bit odbc driver, as expected since I'm on a new Windows 64-bit stack, in the following way:

```
open System.Data
open FSharp.Data.Sql
[<Literal>] 
let dnsConn = @"DSN=MyDSN32" 
type db = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.ODBC, dnsConn>


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let ctx = db.GetDataContext("DSN=MyDSN64")
```

Comment: Nice solution. But why don't you use a direct connection to SQL-Server with `DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER` and a corresponding connection string?